# Is it possible to get the previous day of the week using Joda-Time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I am new to Joda-Time and was looking at getting the previous working/week day. 
My initial try was done on a Monday and I wanted to get the date for T -1 which will be Friday:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
Chronology coptic = GJChronology.getInstance(zone);

DateTime dt = new DateTime(coptic);
DateTime minusOneDay = dt.minusDays(1);

System.out.println(minusOneDay );
```

But as I expected returns the date on Sunday. Does anyone know how to get the previous week day? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: After some more research I now realise that I have to solve a bigger problem than just days of the week. I need holidays in different locations. These holidays change a lot so you will have to subscribe to the changes from someone like http://www.financialcalendar.com/ which you feed into a calendar or use something like http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net/
On thinking about it Joda or any other date libraries will never maintain this information, nor should they as it changes so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look to be handled by Joda time.

There is a sourceforge project that looks to handle it though.

[objectlabkit](http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If the day is Monday or Sunday, then you need to subtract three or two days respectively. In all other cases subtract one day. This assumes a working week from Monday to Friday (which doesn't apply to all cultures).

Comment: I was hoping that you could add a locale or calendar/chronology and that Joda-Time could do it for your. I don't really want to be saying, if it is Friday subtract 3 days and if Friday is a public holiday subtract 4 days etc... 
I want to be lazy and let someone else do this :-)